# Prove $(a, b)=d$ iff $d=au+dv$, and $(a, b)=d$ iff $(x, y)=1$.

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra

Let $a, b, d, x, y \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $dx=a$, $dy=b$, and $d>0$.

1. Use Bézout's Theorem to prove that $(a, b)=d$ if and only if $\exists u, v \in \mathbb{Z}$ s.t. $d=au+bv$.
2. Use 1. to prove that $(a, b)=d$ if and only if $(x, y)=1$.

Starting on 1., I noted that it states if $d\mid a$ and $d\mid b$, then $d=(a, b) \iff \exists u, v \in \mathbb{Z}$ s.t. $d=au+bv$, where the $d\mid a$ and $d\mid b$ is an extra hypothesis compared to Bézout's Theorem. Would using Bézout's Theorem in this problem give you that $a, b$ are integer linear combinations of $a$ and $b$? Since $d\mid a$ and $d\mid b$? When I did that, I get something of the form $dz=au+bv$, which is close to what I want, but the $d$ is not alone and I don't know how to get there.

Comment: What does Bézout's theorem assert, for you?

Comment: Our def says that (1) the gcd(a, b) is the smallest integer linear combination of a and b, and (2) that for $x\in \mathbb{Z}$, $(a, b)|x \iff$ x is an integer linear combination of a and b.

Answer (score 1):

For $1)$, $\Rightarrow $ follows from Bezout's theorem.

For $\Leftarrow $, note that $d=au+bv$ implies any common divisor of $a$ and $b$ divides $d$.  So $d\ge(a,b)$.  But we are given that $d$ is a common divisor. So $d\le(a,b)$.

For $2)$, we get $(a,b)=d\iff \exists u,v$ with $au+bv=d\iff d=dxu+dyv \iff 1=xu+yv\iff (x,y)=1 $.